# Creating an application that determines whether a number is odd/even

Tags: c#, operator-keyword

I am very new to C# and I am having some issues. I have been trying for a while now and I cant seem to get it right. I think I have the idea but I just don't know how to make it work. There aren't any examples in the chapters of my book either. I need to "create an application that reads an integer, then determines and displays whether it’s odd or even. Have the user enter an integer and output to the console:  The number you have entered is:  input value + even or odd" I'm hoping I can get some help here. Not looking for someone to just do the work either. If you can explain it, please do!

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;

    namespace Student_Challenge_Lab_2
    {
       class Program
   {
      // main method begins the execution of C# program
      static void Main(string[] args)
      {
         int number1; // declares the integer to be added

         // following code prompts user to input the two sets of integers
         Console.Write("Please enter your integer: ");
         number1 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

         int %(number1, ); 
         // the program now tests to see if the integer is even or odd. If the remainder is        0 it is an even integer
         if (% == 0)
            Console.Write("Your integer is even.", number1);
         else Console.Write("Your integer is odd.", number1);


          }
       } // end main
    } // end Student challenge lab 2
```

Comment: You need to what operators (eg, `+`) are.

Comment: "integer" is the spelling you are looking for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Every binary operator should be used in a form:

```
[argument1] [THE OPERATOR] [argument2]
```

The `%` is also a binary operator, which can be used in the same way as `+` and `/`. So analogically, if the `/` operator produces the result of a division operation:

```
float result = (float)number1 / number2;
```

the `%` will produce the remainder in the same fashion:

```
int remainder = number1 % number2;
```

All what's left is that numbers that are even produce `0` remainder when modulo against `2` is calculated.

Comment: Point to note: if `number1` and `number2` are `int`s, the `/` there is integer division, the result of which is `int`. The example will compile, but result in what you might not expect, e.g. `5 / 2 == 2`, not 2.5. After the division is done and you have the result of 2, that is then stored as a `float`, so `result == 2.0f`. If you wanted floating division on integer arguments, you could do `(float)number1 / number2`.

Comment: @TimS. Good point. It's a bit irrelevant to the issue being discussed, but I've added it to the answer for the sake of correctness. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how you've come up with the syntax you're using here

```
int %(number1, );
```

You've already defined number1 as an int above. You want to define a new variable that contains the value of your mod operation on number1. So something like:

```
int remainder = number1 % 2;
```

Then

```
if (remainder == 0)
```

Answer (score -1):

Here, I have done your homework...

[The ?? operator is called the null-coalescing operator and is used to define a default value for nullable value types or reference types. It returns the left-hand operand if the operand is not null; otherwise it returns the right operand.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx)

[The % operator computes the remainder after dividing its first operand by its second. All numeric types have predefined remainder operators.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0w4e0fzs.aspx)

I also added a [Console.ReadKey](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/471w8d85.aspx) so that you can see the output, press any key to end the app.

```
    using System;

namespace Student_Challenge_Lab_2
{
    internal class Program
    {
        // main method begins the execution of C# program
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // following code prompts user to input the two sets of integers
            Console.Write("Please enter your integer: ");
            var number1 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            // the program now tests to see if the integer is even or odd. If the remainder is        0 it is an even integer
            Console.Write(number1 % 2 == 0 ? "Your integer ({0}) is even." : "Your integer ({0}) is odd.", number1);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
    // end main
}
// end Student challenge lab 2
```

Comment: @siride - Hit submit by accident, I was off getting links, so that he can research for himself a little too...